# Expo-start: An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: react-native, expo

I am setting up react-native and expo on my machine.
When i run expo start in my terminal i get a blank white screen with the text "**An unexpected error has occurred**" And also when i scan the QR code i get "**Network response timed out**".
I tried following all the steps on setting up my expo environment using the docs so i do not know where i went wrong and how to resolve it.
I even tried deleting and reinstalling expo-cli on my machine.
I am using linux and I have expo-cli@5.6.0 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! Apparently expo-cli v5.4.10 or greater versions has some issues with the web interface. Rolled back to 5.4.9 and DevTools work again now. This is the rollback command

```
npm install expo-cli@5.4.9 --location=global
```

For uninstalling the Previous CLi you can use

```
yarn global remove expo-cli
```

or

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

if you are using npm